# Create 3 different Arrays from a Single Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create 3 separate arrays from a single array of 7 items. What I am doing with the following code is not working properly. And I need your help, please. Thank you.

```
//declara global variables
var i,j; var array_2; var gn; var gl; var gs; var gnArr=[]; var glArr=[]; var gsArr=[]; var array = []; var txtdata;

//get array values from a textarea     
txtdata = document.getElementById("txtdata").value;
```

*these are the values from the TextArea input:*

txtdata = **Distinction:A+:>=75 Alpha:A1:>=75 V.Good:A2:>=75 Good:A3:>=75 Credit:C4:>=75 Pass:P7:>=75 Fail:F9:>=75**

```
// split txtdata using the empty space paramater
array = txtdata.split(" ");  
alert(array.length-1); // length of array[] is 7;

//split each array item of the array[] into 3 different arrays... [0,1,2] using the ":" parameter
for ( i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++ ){ 
    array_2 = array[i].split(":"); //there are 3 array items... 0, 1, 2 in array_2
    gnArr = array_2[0]+":";  glArr = array_2[1]+":";  gsArr = array_2[2]+":";           
} 
alert(gnArr); // this only alerts the last (7th) item of the array[i].
```

But I want to get all array_2[0] for all 7 items of array[i] in gnArr...like this...

**Distinction:Alpha:V.Good:Good:Credit:Pass:Fail**

Same goes for array_2[1] and array_2[2]

**A+:A1:A2:A3:C4:P7:F9**

Comment: You should add the result to the `gnArr` and others using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way: use  `+=`  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment

```js
//declara global variables
var i, j , array_2 
  , gnArr = []
  , glArr = []
  , gsArr = []
  , array = []
  , txtdata = "Distinction:A+:>=75 Alpha:A1:>=75 V.Good:A2:>=75 Good:A3:>=75 Credit:C4:>=75 Pass:P7:>=75 Fail:F9:>=75"
  ;

//get array values from a textarea     
// txtdata = document.getElementById("txtdata").value;

array = txtdata.split(" ");  // split txtdata using the empty space paramater
 
 
for ( i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
  { 
  array_2 = array[i].split(":"); //there are 3 array items... 0, 1, 2 in array_2
  let separator = (i != (array.length -1)) ? ':': ''
  gnArr += array_2[0] + separator
  glArr += array_2[1] + separator
  gsArr += array_2[2] + separator           
  }
  
console.log ('gnArr =', gnArr )
console.log ('glArr =', glArr )
console.log ('gsArr =', gsArr )
```

for info, in a shorter way:

```js
let txtdata = "Distinction:A+:>=75 Alpha:A1:>=75 V.Good:A2:>=75 Good:A3:>=75 Credit:C4:>=75 Pass:P7:>=75 Fail:F9:>=75";
let [gnArr, glArr, gsArr] =
      txtdata
      .split(' ')
      .reduceRight((res,part,i)=>
        {
        part.split(':').forEach((subPart,j)=>res[j].unshift(subPart))
        if (!i) res.forEach((gX,j,r)=>r[j]=gX.join(':'))
        return res
        }
        ,[ [],[],[] ]);                           
            
console.log ('gnArr =', gnArr )
console.log ('glArr =', glArr )
console.log ('gsArr =', gsArr )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, very much. It worked perfectly. Please, could you put me through a bit of a explanation, if you do not mind? Thank you. You're great!

Comment: @Cybernetiquettes If you are really a beginner, then there is a lot of "stuff" in the last code. it starts with a Destructuring assignment then there is the chaining of methods, a little nija code (for the `!i` => eq `i===0`) ... the `reduceRight` method is infrequent...
in short it would be too much to explain here, the MDN documentation should help you, otherwise for each of these subjects this site probably already has all the answers